# Translate pinch and zoom to external display on iPad

Tags: uiscrollview, external

I am presenting fullscreen content on an external display in a uiscrollview. I want to allow pinching and zooming on the iPad which will pinch and zoom the uiscrollview on the external display. How to translate the iPad gestures to the other window?

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to put the UIScrollView on both the iPad AND the external display. I believe that you should just set the iPad's Window root view controller to the same view controller that controls the external display. You could probably "hide" the view on the iPad if you really wanted to, and I could tell you how to do that if you really want to, but it is out of the scope of this question.

Comment: I did not know I could do that! So add it to the subview of the external and also the subview of the ipad window?

Comment: umm that sounds right. You could add it as a subview or set the scrollviewcontroller as the rootviewcontroller of both the windows. If that doesn't work then I might have an alternate solution...

Comment: Still working on - bounty approval will not be forgotten, I promise.